# adding a second pod to my project/podfile, project does not build anymore

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I have a podfile which looks as follows:

> source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
>
> pod 'IQKeyboardManager'
>
> xcodeproj '../myProject.xcodeproj'
>
> workspace 'myProject'

If I run this, using

> pod install

and open the resulting myProject.xcworkspace file,

I can build my project, and it runs fine on any device.

Now I want to add a second dependency to my project: [XMPPFramework](https://github.com/ChatSecure/XMPPFramework/tree/f1364d1dd9bc8d0843b79ee8abe261154473d8a0).

This project has a podspec at [podspec file](https://github.com/ChatSecure/XMPPFramework/blob/f1364d1dd9bc8d0843b79ee8abe261154473d8a0/XMPPFramework.podspec.json)

So I add the podspec name to my podfile.

The file now looks as follows:

> source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
>
> pod 'IQKeyboardManager'
>
> pod 'XMPPFramework'
>
> xcodeproj '../myProject.xcodeproj'
>
> workspace 'myProject'

now, when I run

> pod install

I get the following output:

> Analyzing dependencies
>   [!] There is a circular dependency between XMPPFramework/Authentication and XMPPFramework/Core

I just hope for the best and hope the warning about circular dependencies won't be an issue, and open the myProject.xcworkspace file again.

This time I get an error building:

> clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/myUser/Desktop/myProject/myProject/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-IQKeyboardManager/Pods-IQKeyboardManager-prefix.pch'
>
> clang: error: no input files
>
> Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

So somehow, adding the new pod XMPPFramework seems to break something with the first pod, IQKeyboardManager.

Is anyone aware of why this is happening, and what can be done to get this working?

Thanks!

Best regards,

C

Comment: Have you tried it with Xcode closed? Also, maybe see if there is a version number you can add to get it to work. It seems to be an issue with the pod library.

Comment: Yes, I just tried that as well. Same problem. I also tried reversing the order in which I add the pods. Same problem, though I don't know whether that should change anything anyway. When you say it may be an issue with the pod library, you mean it is a problem on the end of XMPPFramework and/or it's podspec, not an issue on my end here on my machine?

Comment: another option would be that pod#2 is changing/overriding some setting that pod#1 needs, but I have no idea how to check that, as I am fairly new to xcode/pods..

Comment: Yes it could be either one of those. Check your build settings - Header Search and make sure $(inherited) is in there. The error looks as though the .pch file goes missing. Also something to try is to remove the xcodeproj and the workspace lines from your podfile and retry the install.

Comment: the header search path looks like this `$(inherited) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include`. If I remove the xcodeproj and workspace lines, on pod install I get `[!] Could not automatically select an Xcode project. Specify one in your Podfile like so:

    xcodeproj 'path/to/Project.xcodeproj'`                           If I remove only the workspace line, but not the xcodeproj line, i can install, but get the same problem when I build, about the precompiled header file

Comment: Huh, I have never had the xcodeproj in my podfiles. I am sure you have checked, but your podfile is in your project root folder? Are there multiple xcode projects in that folder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66687/discussion-between-siriss-and-user2011985).